# how to display a toast after 10 seconds from starting Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, task, execute, toast

please suggest me how to execute something after 10 seconds from the start of AsyncTask.
I have used AsyncTask for different purpose. But, now I want to update my UI after 10 seconds.
Or to show a toast after specific time.

I actually want to perform some other task after 10 seconds, while the original task is running

please let me know how to do this.?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use any view instead of handler in onPreExecute method of your async task like:

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, 10000);
    };
```

Comment: what should be the view in case I want to show the toast, after 10 seconds?

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm you can use any view. or if you havent any you can create a handler. also runable will be run in main thread, so you can show toast without any problems

Comment: @ Alex Klimashevsky. Can you please suggest any link of this kind of logic?

Comment: @nick as written below http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29 :) but just simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android's CountdownTimer on `onPreExecute` of AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

And set countdowntimer to 10 secs (10000 ms).
Its easy to use.

Comment: in your AsyncTasks onPreExecute function.

Answer (score 0):

Go for timer task.
The TimerTask class represents a task to run at a specified time. The task may be run once or repeatedly.
here is the link :-
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Handler in your UI Thread and Toast with [Handler.postDelayed(Runnable runnable, long delayMillis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).